# full screen custom dialog on android

Tags: android

recently , I have custom dialog code.

I want full screen custom dialog.

How can I full screen custom dialog on android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static Process rebootProcess;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Warning~~");
    builder.setMessage("reboot")
            .setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    try {
                        rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "poweroff"});
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);`

Comment: horizontal is fullscreen   but vertical is no full screen

Comment: are you talking about the orientation

Answer (score 0):

Inside onCreate, Create a dialog

//Design layout file as full screen

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this);
// set other paramters for dialog
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
```

Comment: perhaps, have you  your_layout_file     source ?

Comment: your_layout_file is the layout you want to show. Add whatever you want to display in dialog in layout file

Comment: seperately  not create layout_file  ,  show full screen dialog ?